# Post Restful Authentication

Tags: mean-stack, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I am using MEAN stack for developing a web application. I choose it be completely RESTFULL that is stateless. For authentication I am using JWT(Json Web Token) strategy.

Client sends login request to server, server authenticates and sends JWT and user data to the client(here angular 2).I am storing this JWT token in the cookie.

Now my question is how do we store/display user details in the view continuously. For eg if we consider Facebook as restful , after a user logs in, client display user data such as profile image, profile link etc etc.

Since Rest Authentication just retrieves the data, with credentials sent in each request.

How are these user related data retained in the client side. Is it like for each request, user data is fetched from the server and updated continuously in the view.

If yes how or if no then am I missing something.

I know this question might be nonsense to experts, but any advice, suggestion or kickstarter information would be helpful for a novice like me.Are there any best practises for these?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can fetch user data from server on every request but the right approach is to store it in JWT token as custom claims and on each request get the token from cookie, decode it and get the necessary details from those custom claims.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But storing details in cookie can be easily edited in the browser(from client side). If only JWT token is stored and somebody edits it. I can check its validity through server communication, but if user details is encoded and stored. Decoding those tampered user details may lead to unwanted results right?

Comment: 1) JWT signing also includes payload (the custom claims). This means that tempered payload will make JWT invalid.
2) It is recommended to use SSL (HTTPS) when getting JWT tokens. 
3) There is also a JWE specification that defines additional JWT token encryption.

Comment: Any how even the JWT token can be easily modified in the client side. To validate that I have to send JWT in every request to server (I am storing in cookies) and if its invalid I have to redirect user to login page. Is my understanding right???

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can store user data in localStorage for frequent use.

Comment: localStorage is vulnerable to XSS attacks.